# How to keep ubuntu one from deleting items when there is a conflict

Tags: ubuntu-one

Question: Every now and then when I get a conflict on ubuntu one it deletes the file and leaves just the .u1conflict file.

---

Info:

Last night I spent 5 hours working on a python program I called Facere.py, I made a folder for it of the same name, Facere. This was happening on my desktop. Now earlier in the day I knew I wanted to do this so I had made the folders on my netbook, but promptly got distracted so they didn't have a chance to sync. So I recreated them on my Desktop and didn't open my netbook to let the sync just happen. 5 hours go by. I have done a fair chunk of work on Facere.py and made a couple dev docs in facere/, its now mid night so I got to bed.

I get to class and open my netbook and i see facere.u1conflict/. wide eyed i look in it and see only facere.py (who has one line "from TKinter import *"). I proceed to check my phone, facere/ doesn't exist, i check my desktop, folder is gone there too, I check one.ubuntu.com as a last hope. nothing.

The work I did last night was mostly educational and I could probably recreate it better than it was in about half an hour. What I'm really concerned with is that this isn't the first time something like this has happened. what is happening that Ubuntu one is deleting my files every now and then? it is really disconcerting and kind of makes ubuntu one less enticing to people when I brag to windows users about how I never worry about loosing my data because it is in the cloud.

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your trash bin, it might still be there on whichever device you used to create the lost file. I normally delete my files permanently when I'm done, which made it obvious that Ubuntu One recently started sending out-of-date files to the trash instead of renaming them.

Comment: I think that's it. Thanks. peace of mind restored. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One is not a proper tool to perform version control of source codes. The reason for that is that it knows nothing about the contents of the files and treat each file as an opaque binary blob - i.e. if both versions of a file were modified it has no way to merge them of to do anything meaningful apart from marking them as conflicted.

For any text-based file formats and especially for program sources I would strongly recommend to use a proper version control system - which, apart from ability to merge files, has tons of other features specifically designed for this kind of distributed work (for one thing, even if something went terribly wrong, you always can roll-back to a previous version of a file).

Get yourself a free account at [github](http://github.com) and be happy :)

Comment: the source code was just incidental. This has happend to pictures, songs, and other binary files that it is quite appropriate to have in ubuntu one. I'm not using it as a version control per se, I just happen to store minor projects on it for convenience. I'm not to upset because I've not lost much. for larger projects I do have a git server sitting right here with me to manage just that. The problem is that it marks one item as a conflict, typically the older one, and deletes the other. I can't conflict resolve when I only have 1 of the 2 files. that's my question, why do I only have 1 file?